# 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_compile_metrics'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My `tensorflow` is version `2.4.1`

i imported modules like this

```
### import modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import pandas as pd
import scipy

%matplotlib inline
```

Then i try to create simple compile model like this

```
def compile_model(model):
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

So my testing function is like this

```
test_model = Sequential([Dense(100),
                        Dense(2, activation='softmax')])
compile_model(test_model)
assert isinstance(test_model.optimizer, tf.keras.optimizers.Adam)
assert hasattr(test_model, 'loss')
assert test_model.loss == 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
assert ['accuracy'] == test_model._compile_metrics
del test_model
```

After i ran above code blocks i got this error
`AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_compile_metrics'`

[image]

But i can't seems find any actual document about `_compile_metrics`

Am i missing something or is it about tensorflow version?
Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: The `compile_model` function does not return anything!

Comment: @M.Innat Okay, I just saw something similar online, but now I read in documentation. You are correct.

Comment: @M.Innat should not the model carry on the compile like a reference type?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The answer by OP will only work in `TF 2.0, 2.1` only. From `TF 2.2 - 2.5`, it won't work.

---

To get the metric name, like `accuracy` you have to run the model at least one epoch or on a single batch.

```
def compile_model(model):
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
test_model = Sequential([Dense(256, ),
                        Dense(2, activation='softmax')])
compile_model(test_model)
assert isinstance(test_model.optimizer, tf.keras.optimizers.Adam)
assert hasattr(test_model, 'loss')
assert test_model.loss == 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
```

Run-on single epoch with dummy set

```
test_model.fit(x = np.random.uniform(0,1, (37432,512)),
               y = np.random.randint(0,2, (37432,1)))

test_model.loss # sparse_categorical_crossentropy
test_model.metrics_names # ['loss', 'accuracy']

assert 'loss' == test_model.metrics_names[0]
assert 'accuracy' == test_model.metrics_names[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is about the version, so the sample that i got suppose to run on Tensorflow 2.0.0 but i ran it on 2.4.0 so if i ran the code in 2.0.0 then it works fine.